# Where in the registry can I found mounted devices?

Tags: windows-7, usb, mount, windows-registry

I'm writing a python application on Windows 7 (64bit) where I need to start something after a new USB storage device has been mounted. In an older application I was polling on `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` for changes and I want to do the same approach for a new USB device.

Does anyone know where in the registry I might do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I can poll for changes in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\USBSTOR\Enum'

Answer (score 0):

[this site](http://diddy.boot-land.net/firadisk/files/mounteddevices.htm) sais it's here : `HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices`

Comment: I thought so to, but if I unplug on of the devices with drive letters nothing happens in that registry